# How do I make an SVG dynamically scale with it's parent div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a small HTML file with an inline SVG object. Currently, the displayed SVG is quite large and the user needs to zoom out to see it fully. I want to make it so that 100% of the SVG is scaled within it's parent div, but I'm having issues doing this through CSS. Additionally, I'm trying to find a way to do this without needing to edit the SVG file itself, and hopefully I could cycle between any SVG file and it would scale the same.

As an example, here are small chunks of the actual files I'm working with:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
        <title>OMIX Map</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>OMIX MAP</h1>
        <div id="map">
            <object id="map-svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/map.svg" onload="loadSVG()"></object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:omix="http://www.omix.bio/xsd/omixsvg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="tiny" height="2541" version="1.2" width="2298" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>Network 'Homo sapiens'</title>
  <desc>Created with Omix</desc>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPath1">
      <path d="M0,0 L2298.591,0 L2298.591,2541.682 L0,2541.682 L0,0"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="7.5px" font-style="normal" font-weight="400" id="ID3f9bfff0" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1">
    <g class="Metabolite" id="Metabolite$NADH$3" name="NADH" omix:clone="3">
      <g class="Shape" id="Shape_of_Metabolite$NADH$3">
        <path d="M-30,-15 C-30,-17.761 -27.851,-20 -25.2,-20 L25.2,-20 C27.851,-20 30,-17.761 30,-15 L30,15 C30,17.761 27.851,20 25.2,20 L-25.2,20 C-27.851,20 -30,17.761 -30,15 L-30,-15" fill="#a28dff" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" id="ID3f089e5e" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" transform="matrix(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1206.0929206118517,898.2429901388446)" vector-effect="none"/>
      </g>
      <g class="Label" id="Label_of_Metabolite$NADH$3">
        <text fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="18px" font-style="normal" font-weight="700" id="ID4037e797" stroke="none" transform="matrix(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1173.6866706118517,883.2429901388446)" x="4.812" xml:space="preserve" y="22">NADH</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}

#map-svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you using `<object>` instead of `<img>` to load your svg ?

Comment: I want to be able to interact with the different SVG elements with javascript

Comment: Since `<object>` is an inline element, assign `display: block` to `#map-svg` in CSS.
If you want to have it responsive, perhaps `height: auto; max-width: 100%` would make sense, too. (Can only tell from `<img />` offhand)

Comment: I don't understand using `position: fixed;top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` will make the image fill the entire screen which is quite large unlike what you want. Do you mind clearing things up a bit ? all you need to do to make a child stay within it's parent is limit it's width and height width `max-width, max-height` but if the parent is huge then i don't know

Comment: Don't use an `object` use the actual SVG.